# Casting an Interface to a Generic Class(WIth inheritance)

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following structure in code:

```
AController<S> : IScreenController where T : IProperties {}

FOOTypeControllers<T> : AController<T> where T : IScreenProperties
{
}

MyFooTypeController : FOOTypeControllers<MyProperties>
{
}

class MyProperties : IProperties {}
```

What I want to do is cast a type of MyFooTypeController to FOOTypeControllers but I get an invalid cast error.
 Why is this not allowed since it does inherit from the class.

This is Exactly How Im trying to cast:

```
void MyFucntion(IScreenController screenController)
{
  FOOTypeControllers<IProperties> screenControl = (FOOTypeControllers<IProperties>) screenController
}
```

Each Subclass of FOOTypeControllers will also use a a different subclass of Iproperties.

Comment: While every `FOOTypeControllers<T>` **is** an  `IScreenControler`, not every `IScreenControler` is a `FOOTypeControllers<T>`. Or in other words: while every `Cat` is an `Animal`, not every `Animal` is a `Cat`.

Comment: well I can do a Check with the "IS" keyword before casting but it always returns false...

Comment: You will need co-variance to achieve this. Basically a `Derived<T>` does **not** derive from `Base<S>`, even though `T`inherits from `S`. So you can´t cast to your base-class. In fact not even `Derived<T>` will derive from `Derived<S>`, both types don´t have anything in common and you can´t cast one to another, even though `T` inherits from `S`.

Comment: Can you point me or link me to an example that shows how I can use covariance to acheive this?

Comment: I looked at covariance examples but Im still confused as to how I can convert my scenario to that since they are using generic interfaces and I am not.